# asp.net core - pass exception description to client (e.g. Angular)

Tags: asp.net, angular, exception, asp.net-core, http-headers

I've been trying to fetch exception text from backend (ASP.NET Core) in Angular app.

I've seen examples where the controller action's return type is `JsonResult` or `ActionResult`.

In this case we can do the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetSomething()
{
    ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { error = $"{ex.GetType().FullName}: '{ex.Message}'" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

All controller actions I have return DTOs, e.g.

```
public async Task<List<OrderDto>> GetMany(long clientId)
{
    ....
```

Since I'm returning DTO - I can't seem to return `Json`, so the approach above doesn't work.

I wonder if there's a way to pass exception description other than via `Json(...)`.

Does anyone have an idea of how to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a middleware:

```
public class ExceptionHandleMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public ExceptionHandleMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.ContentType = @"application/json";


            await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { error = $"{ex.GetType().FullName}: '{ex.Message}'"}));
        }
    }
}
```

And then add it to application Builder in Configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ....
    app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandleMiddleware>();
}
```

Pay attention that with this middleware you shouldn't catch your exception on Controller level.

Comment: Excellent answer. Just would like to mention I had to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers - and that's it.